# can't pass a variable into a function in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame `cat_data` which has a column `workclass`:

```
> cat_data$workclass
   [1] "State-gov"        "Self-emp-not-inc" "Private"          "Private"          "Private"    ... [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 31561 entries ]
```

And column `y` is

```
> cat_data$y
   [1] "<=50K" "<=50K" "<=50K" "<=50K" "<=50K" "<=50K" "<=50K" ">50K"  ">50K"  ">50K"  ">50K"  ">50K"  "<=50K"   ...[ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 31561 entries ]
```

I wrote a script to prepare for Naive Bayes analysis:

```
library(dplyr)
workclass <- cat_data %>%
  group_by(workclass, y) %>%
  summarise(num = n()) %>%
  spread(y, num) %>%
  ungroup()
```

It gave me what I want:

```
> workclass
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  workclass        `<=50K` `>50K`
  <chr>              <int>  <int>
1 ?                   1645    191
2 Federal-gov          589    371
3 Local-gov           1476    617
4 Never-worked           7     NA
5 Private            17733   4963
6 Self-emp-inc         494    622
7 Self-emp-not-inc    1817    724
8 State-gov            945    353
9 Without-pay           14     NA
```

Since I need to the same data preparation many times and I don't want to rewrite this chunk again and again, I decided to write a function:

```
get_frequency <- function(column){
  cat_data %>%
    group_by(column, y) %>%
    summarise(num = n()) %>%
    spread(y, num) %>%
    ungroup()
}
```

When I tried `workclass <- get_frequency(workclass)`, it threw an error:

```
Error: Column `column` is unknown
```

How can I fix it?

## update: I've been able to fix it.

```
library(rlang)
get_frequency <- function(column){
  column <- enquo(column)
  column <- cat_data %>%
    group_by(!!column, y) %>%
    summarise(num = n()) %>%
    spread(y, num) %>%
    ungroup()
  return(column)
}
> workclass <- get_frequency(workclass)
> workclass
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  workclass        `<=50K` `>50K`
  <chr>              <int>  <int>
1 ?                   1645    191
2 Federal-gov          589    371
3 Local-gov           1476    617
4 Never-worked           7     NA
5 Private            17733   4963
6 Self-emp-inc         494    622
7 Self-emp-not-inc    1817    724
8 State-gov            945    353
9 Without-pay           14     NA
```

Thanks erveybody!

Comment: Please add reproducible sample data; this is a matter of properly quoting/unquoting `column` inside your function to adhere to `dplyr`'s non-standard evaluation.

Comment: Add a `dput` of data. What is `y` in your function?

Comment: To write a function that takes a column name as an argument like this, you'll need to do some [tidyeval](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)

Answer (score 0):

Mauritus Evers is correct and their are a few ways of doing this. My preferred method (and seems most correct from reading up on it) is to use the `!!` operator from `rlang` package, it works well and also has a `!!!` for unquoting and splicing a vector of arguments for evaluation which comes in handy if you wanted to pass multiple columns to be evaluated in `group_by`. This unquotes the argument and evaluates it in the surrounding environment.

Some of the ways I have done it in the past:

- `!!` operator from `rlang`: This unquotes the argument and evaluates it in the surrounding environment
- eval(parse(text = "column")): Which as the call would suggest, evaluates the parsed argument in the surrounding environment.
- Last method is to use `group_by_` function which is the SE (standard evaluation) versions of the `dplyr` verb `group_by` which allows for exactly what Mauritus Evers referred to.

Bearing in mind that it matters whether you pass a string "column" or object into your function. But play around with those options and you'd get it working in the way you prefer.

Example:

```
get_frequency <- function(column){
  cat_data %>%
    group_by(!! sym(column), y) %>%
    summarise(num = n()) %>%
    spread(y, num) %>%
    ungroup()
}
get_frequency("column")
```

Alternatively if you would like to not pass a string

```
get_frequency <- function(column){
  cat_data %>%
    group_by(!! enquo(column), y) %>%
    summarise(num = n()) %>%
    spread(y, num) %>%
    ungroup()
}

get_frequency(column)
```

Comment: Please edit to show how you would actually change up the function to make it work. The text is good but an executable example is great! Also note:`group_by_() is deprecated. 
Please use group_by() instead`

Comment: Thanks! This is informative.